# Is a semicolon delimiter a good way to store a large number of ID #s in a mysql field?

Tags: mysql

I have a database which will store millions of Post ID#s.    I need to associate with each post ID # a number of User ID #s (on the order of about 20-50 for each post ID).  I was thinking of constructing a semicolon delimited list in PHP and just inserting that into a DB field on the post ID row.

Is this a relativly efficient and good way to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: **No.**

Comment: Slightly longer answer: Heck no. This will be setting yourself up for eons of misery and suffering. What you need is a many-to-many mapping table. Easily queried and much more efficient. Depending on your use case this may not be true in an, ahem, better DB, like Postgres that supports array columns.

Comment: If you want to kill your MySQL server Yes... if you want to keep performance No ... this should be really an many to many relationship

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long answer to this is you need to create a one-to-many association table. Proper [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) principles dictate this.

The problem with your approach, serializing the list into the database as a semicolon-concatenated list, is the data itself is virtually useless unless you can deserialize it.

Fields of this sort:

- Cannot be indexed effectively.
- Can grow to exceed the storage capacity of the column.
- Require context to properly utilize.
- Cannot work with foreign key integrity checking.
- Cannot be easily amended.
- Removing entires requires re-writing the entire field.
- Cannot be queried directly.
- Cannot be used in `JOIN` operations.

You're talking about creating a simple association table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_posts (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT,
  post_id INT
)
```

You'd have a `UNIQUE` index on `user_id,post_id` to ensure that you don't have duplicates. The inclusion of an `id` column is mostly so you can remove particular rows without having to specify user+post pairs.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a very bad idea.

A `foreign key` is what you want here. Basically, for every `post_ID` you also store the `USER ID` as a foreign key.

So, if you have a `POSTS` table, you add a column `User_ID` (or `Poster_ID`) and reference the `USER ID` in the `USER` table.

I think you should review some of the basics - please see links:

- http://www.functionx.com/sql/Lesson11.htm
- http://creately.com/blog/diagrams/er-diagrams-tutorial/
- https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~gweddell/cs348/errelational-handout.pdf